# Drupal workbench for each department

Tags: workflows, workbench

I'm new to drupal and would like to build a workflow with the below functionality.

[image]

I'm able to create extra states through workbench module.

But the above workflow needs to be applied for each department in the company. ex:- Library services, Finance, Tourism. Therefore each department has different content authors and department managers, but the Marketing team will be the same for the entire company.

I'm guessing there should be a way to specify the department from a dropdown menu or something (with the help of taxonomy) so that when a new node is created from a specific content type, the content creator can specify the department which it should be forwarded to.

Can anyone please tell me how I should create this through workbench?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [Workbench Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access) and a Roles per department and 1 Marketing Role to make this happen.

> Workbench Access creates editorial access controls based on
>   hierarchies. It is an extensible system that supports structures
>   created by other Drupal modules.
>
> When creating and editing content, users will be asked to place the
>   content in an editorial section. Other users within that section or
>   its parents will be able to edit the content. A user may be granted
>   editorial rights to a section specific to his account or by his
>   assigned role on the site.

So you place Finance Editors (a role) users in the finance `section`, and Finance Manager(s) in the finance `section`. And the Marketing role is assigned to the root level section (which implies all subsections -- and secretly adds that role to each section).

So prior to using the site you would have to assign each user into sections of the site, which Workbench has an Administration page for.

Workbench Access provides 2 means to define `sections` out of the box. A section can be a menu path, or Taxonomy terms. Additionally you can create your own section logic using the supplied API functions of the workbench suite.

Be aware that Workbench only works on `Node` based content (unless this has since changed since I last checked). So for instance you cannot create [Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) and moderate them, messages are (custom) Entities.

**EDIT:**

I suggest seeing the official linked [Documentation of Workbench Access](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/workbench_access) and reading all the info and further 3rd party videos/documentation on that page.